# Do I need dependency properties for all basic properties on my user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am currently writing my first user control which would consist of a label and a text box in a stack panel like follows:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Label}" Width="60"></Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxContent}" Width="60"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This will be most useful to be in a settings page, as it will be reused for several different settings. With each of these settings, I will want to set (at a minimum) the width, height, validation rule and error template properties. As for the text itself, I have already created a dependency property both for the label and the text box (as you can see in my snippet above).

My question is this: Do I need to create a dependency property for all of the properties I just mentioned that I would like to set when I actually use my user control? This seems like redundant work (since they already exist on the text box, basically they would just redirect my user control's property to the text box's property of the same name)? This is even more work if I want to use even more properties on my text box (for example, AcceptsReturn, etc).

Comment: Unless there's something in TextBox you want NOT to have, just subclass TextBox. Or TextBoxBase. That said, a property must be a dependency property to be a binding target, and to be a (useful) binding source (unless you support INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged when it's value changes. I've never tried the latter on a control, so I can't say if it'll work; I generate DPs with snippets, so they're no big hassle.) So maybe some don't *need* to be DPs.

Comment: _"basically they would just redirect my user control's property to the text box's property of the same name"_ -- why would they do that? Why wouldn't e.g. your `UserControl.Width` and `Height` properties control the width and height of the user control itself? Shouldn't you layout the `TextBox` and other children _based on_ the dimensions of their container, i.e. the `UserControl`? If you do want easy pass-through, maybe it makes more sense for you to just create a `ControlTemplate` and use `{TemplateBinding}` inside, instead of a whole `UserControl`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Haven't thought about that. Doing that though, wouldn't I need to manually bind in my XAML each property of my "real" TextBox to the property of my user control that inherits from the TextBox class? Something like

`<TextBox Text={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Path=Text}} Width="60"/> // Untested code`

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are right in the case of height and width (thanks for that, I will correct my approach regarding that), but what about all the other properties?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to bind stuff you wanted to pass in, but at least you wouldn't have to waste time redefining properties. See also what @PeterDuniho says about templates and TemplateBinding -- you'd be doing things a bit differently.

Comment: _"what about all the other properties"_ -- that depends on what they are and how you're using them. But a validation rule would be applied at a binding, and you can just as easily validate the surfaced property on the `UserControl` as pass a validation rule down to an embedded child. Arguably an error template should apply to the user control as well; client code shouldn't know about the internals of the user control, but they'd have to for it to make sense for them to provide an error template that's intended to be applied to the embedded child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redundant work can be saved if you decide to derive from `TextBox` rather than `UserControl` - just think of your control as a "labeled textbox" and all you need to do is derive from `TextBox` and add the needed dependency properties to accommodate for the label. This of course would not be the case for more complex user controls, but it seems OK in your case.

The downside to this though is that you'll have to take the default control template for `TextBox` and work with it to add your label, which may be a bit trickier.

Either way, I recommend having a look at the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, which is extremely useful when writing your first controls in WPF.